# Generate Truth Table but leave some variables undefined in python

Tags: python

input:

```
vv = [True, False, None, True, None]
```

Is there a way to generate truth table by replacing undefined one boolean at a time
So the ouptut would be

```
[True, False, True, True, None]
[True, False, False, True, None]
[True, False, None, True, False]
[True, False, None, True, True]
```

Comment: What is `Undefined` here ?

Comment: These variables have no value assigned yet, so they are listed as undefined.

Comment: So are these variable have some default value assigned, because you just use variable name without assigning some value. Or else it will give you NameError. Or do you want to store them in string format?

Comment: Can you show example of `These variables have no value assigned` variable?

Comment: `l = [None] * n` where n is the number of values you want. There is no Undefined in Python. Maybe you're confusing it with JS, which has undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that Undefined can be None, for example, you could do as follows:

```
l = [True, False, None, True, None]

# first get indices of None/Undefined elements in the input list
indexes = [i for i,v in enumerate(l) if v is None]

# for each index, generate new list using True and False
# as substitutes.
for idx in indexes:
    for sub in [True, False]:
        new_l = l[:]
        new_l[idx] = sub
        print(new_l)
```

This gives:

```
[True, False, True, True, None]
[True, False, False, True, None]
[True, False, None, True, True]
[True, False, None, True, False]
```